# custom animation of object (animal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, animation

I have seen animation, and i can't figure out how to do something like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hly8KsEPiok)(youtube). I want to discuss how it's made. I don't think that they're using sprites.

I have one idea how to do this: for example i want to create animation of "walking" animal (when animal moves, he's legs "runs" moving animation), i should create customView with imageView of animalBody [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1mdB.png) and two imageViews of animal legs [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSdey.png). Then i make hard coded animation of moving legs and voila, i have custom animation. When i move customView, then i should start animation of legs. But is there better approach to do this? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should probably look into existing libraries for sprite handling. I use cocos2d. Your question is opinion based however, and I am about to close vote it. It may be better on [programmer.se]

Comment: thanks anyway, it's just i'm wondering how to make this using UIKit

Comment: SpriteKit may be of more use

Comment: Yea, spriteKit is great tool. But it doesn't look like they're using sprites in app that i linked.

Comment: Really?? `In computer graphics, a sprite, is a two-dimensional image or animation that is integrated into a larger scene`. Sprite is really just a fancy name for "image"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simplistic effect, you can save the left and right feet as separate images, you can then invoke a repeating, autoreversing animation the `transform` property of each, independently, that rotates the leg image, e.g. something like:

```
// start one foot animation immediately

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.leftFootImageView.transform = [self calculateTransformForFootToAngle:M_PI / 8.0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        self.leftFootImageView.transform = [self calculateTransformForFootToAngle:-M_PI / 8.0];
    } completion:NULL];
}];

// delay the second foot's animation a bit, if you want
// (if you don't want to change the timing of the right foot, you
// could just combine the setting of the right foot's `transform`
// in the above block)

double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.rightFootImageView.transform = [self calculateTransformForFootToAngle:M_PI / 8.0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
            self.rightFootImageView.transform = [self calculateTransformForFootToAngle:-M_PI / 8.0];
        } completion:NULL];
    }];
});
```

Clearly, you need a method for calculating the `CGAffineTransform` value:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)calculateTransformForFootToAngle:(CGFloat)angle
{
    // translate up, rotate, and then translate back, so that the rotation takes place at the top of the leg

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -15);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
    return CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, 15);
}
```

The above assumes that you've defined the individual foot images to be really small, just the boundary of the feet and not all of that whitespace. You'll have to play around with translation values that make sense for your images.

Finally, when you want to stop the animation, you can then just animate the legs back to the identity transform:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    self.leftFootImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.rightFootImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:NULL];
```

Comment: wow, thanks. But i'm wondering if, for example, i will have 10-15 of these objects, will it become laggy?

Comment: @anonymous As long as what you're performing this `transform` on is small image views, it should be pretty efficient. I have 64 legs wiggling at different speeds on iPhone 3GS and it was very smooth at 60fps. Certainly at some point, you'll eventually experience degradation, but it's surprisingly efficient (if you're careful).

Comment: @anonymous By the way, looking at that video, they may also be using `CAKeyFrame` animations (e.g. the wiggle in one direction for a bit and then wiggle in another direction for a bit, and then repeat).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make every single photo that you want to use. So in Photoshop (or your software) you would make lets say 30 pictures, all the same resolution and size, of the animal "running" (move the legs a tiny bit in each photo) You only need one image view, not 3. Remember, your regular video is 30 frames per second. So your going to want to have at least 20 pictures if your going to have that animation play once for one second. Heres the code that your going to want to use in your .m file:

```
- (IBAction)animation{
animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-1"], //use your image names here, put the names in in order, I recommend making the images initially with a number to tell you which one in the sequence it is
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-2"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-3"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-4"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-5"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-6"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-7"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-8"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-9"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-10"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-11"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-12"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-13"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-14"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-15"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-16"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-17"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-18"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-19"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-20"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-21"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-22"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-23"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-24"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-25"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-26"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-27"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"PR-P-28"],nil]; //make sure to have nil!


animationView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //sets how many times it repeats, do a huge number for infinate
animationView.animationDuration = 2.5; //sets how long one repeat takes
[animationView startAnimating]; //starts the animation

}
```

Then declare an `IBOutlet` in your .h file which should be a `UIImageView` named `animationView`

If you want another animation, just use the same code as above, change the name of the `IBAction` and create another `IBOutlet` in your .h file, which is going to be, again, a `UIImageView` and name it the same thing as your `IBAction` for example, if you made another IBAction called playViolin, you would have the IBOutlet in your .h file be playViolin

Then in your .xib file, make a new Image View, and hook up `animationView` to it from the file's owner and you should be set. Just call `[self animation]` when you want it to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice tutorial where it is good explaine:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/